# I tryed to connect my input to the output of my graph in shiny - but I always get an error

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I apologize in case this questions sounds too basic, but I have been trying already for a while and it still doesn't work. (I saw there was a similar question already here but after trying to implement what was suggested there I still received an error). So I would be very grateful if somebody could explain to me in more detail what I do wrong with an example of code.

I have the following data set:

```
year <- c(2000, 2002, 2006, 2000, 2004, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2020, 2006)
prices <- c(100, 200, 300, 120, 240, 400, 430, 490, 700, 650)
colors1 <- c("red", "red", "blue", "green","blue", "red", "blue", "green", "green", "red")
size <- c("s", "m", "l", "xl", "l", "s", "m", "xl", "l","m")
city <- c("NY","LA", "DC","NY","LA", "DC","NY","LA", "DC", "NY")
delivery <- c(3, 7, 3, 10, 20, 5, 10, 2, 12,4)
df <- data.frame(year, prices, colors1,size,city, delivery, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$vatprice<- df$prices * 1.2
```

This is the structure of my data set.
It looks basically like this.

```
   year prices colors1 size city delivery vatprices
1  2000    100     red    s   NY        3       120
2  2002    200     red    m   LA        7       240
3  2006    300    blue    l   DC        3       360
4  2000    120   green   xl   NY       10       144
5  2004    240    blue    l   LA       20       288
6  2010    400     red    s   DC        5       480
7  2010    430    blue    m   NY       10       516
8  2011    490   green   xl   LA        2       588
9  2020    700   green    l   DC       12       840
10 2006    650     red    m   NY        4       780
```

**Now what I am trying to do**
I want to create a small shiny App which would show the following:

**on the x-axis** a range of years (as you can see my years are descrete but I hope I can still set them as a range)

**on y axis:** either price or vatprice

and all this data should be **categorized** either by color, size or city.

```
ui <- basicPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("range", "Year:",min = 1990, max = 2040, value = c(2000,2020)),textOutput("SliderText"),
    selectInput("yaxis", "Y Variable", names(df[,c(2,7)]), selected = names(df)[[2]]),
    radioButtons(inputId = "cat", label = "Categorized by:", names(df[,c(3:5)]))
  ), # closing of the sidebar panel
  plotOutput("scatter")

)


# server 

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

  my_range <- reactive({
    cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
  })
  output$SliderText <- renderText({my_range()})

  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df, aes(df$year, df$prices)) + 
   geom_point(aes(color = factor(df$size))) + labs(title = "Overview",
                  color = "Legend") + xlab("Year") + ylab("Price") + theme_minimal()

  })})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So when I run the programm I get basically already my entire UI and the graph itself. But I have to connect somehow my df data set with the server in order to make my shiny app interactive.

**So my question is: Do I have to create a reactive variable for each of those columns? Or should I just create one reactive data set? Can somebody show me the logic behind, cause I still feel lost.**

I tried to do it like here: [How do I connect my inputs to my graph outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526839/how-do-i-connect-my-inputs-to-my-graph-outputs)
but still got an error - so I removed it and kept only my basic UI and server function, since they don't show any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to get a final df in terms of year range and column names based on what the user has entered. Then we need to pass these variables to `ggplot` using `!!sym` since they will be in string form i.e `prices` will be `"prices"` not `prices`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

  my_range <- reactive({
    cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
  })

  df_final <- reactive({
    filter(df, between(year,input$range[1],input$range[2])) %>% 
    select(year,input$yaxis,input$cat) 
  })

  output$SliderText <- renderText({my_range()})

  #Check if filter and select work correctly and as we wanted
  observe(print(str(df_final()))) 

  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df_final(), aes(year, !!sym(input$yaxis))) + 
      geom_point(aes(color = factor(!!sym(input$cat)))) + labs(title = "Overview",
                                                      color = "Legend") + xlab("Year") + ylab("Price") + theme_minimal()

  })})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Amazing this works !
Thank you so much !
I have a question regarding your code.

Why are you using !!sym

Because I was doing before df[,input$cat] & df[,input$yaxis] and had the same result as you - however, my x-axis did not function but with your solution it does. What are the differences between my and your way ?

Why cant I also just do x= df[ ,input=range] ?

Comment: @Newbie you're most welcome. Both `df[,input$cat]` and `!!sym(input$yaxis)` work in this case but if you comment/removed `ylab("Price")` and `color = "Legend"` you will see the difference, see [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) and [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more details about `sym` and `quo`.You may use `x= df[ ,input=range]` or any subset method taking into account the user inputs but I'm some what a fan of tidyverse ;)

Answer (score 0):

I propose another answer, I made several change, first I inspired myself from the basic tutorial :

https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson4/

Secondly I use aes_string as in :

[Best way to convert character strings in to function arguments in R/ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429749/best-way-to-convert-character-strings-in-to-function-arguments-in-r-ggplot2)

It seems to me more natural for what I did. Secondly I made the selection inside the server I don't know if it is efficient but I think that it is clear. Secondly your `cbind` inside `data.frame` call is a bad idea beacause you force every variable to be the same type and it is not what you want.

```
year <- c(2000, 2002, 2006, 2000, 2004, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2020, 2006)
Price <- c(100, 200, 300, 120, 240, 400, 430, 490, 700, 650)
colors1 <- c("red", "red", "blue", "green","blue", "red", "blue", "green", "green", "red")
size <- c("s", "m", "l", "xl", "l", "s", "m", "xl", "l","m")
city <- c("NY","LA", "DC","NY","LA", "DC","NY","LA", "DC", "NY")
delivery <- c(3, 7, 3, 10, 20, 5, 10, 2, 12,4)
df <- data.frame(year,
                 Price,
                 colors1,
                 size, city,
                 delivery)

df$Vatprice <- df$Price * 1.2

str(df)

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("range",
                "Year:", min = 1990,
                max = 2040, value = c(2000, 2020)),
    textOutput("SliderText"),
    selectInput("yaxis",
                "Y Variable",
                names(df[,c(2,7)]),
                selected = names(df)[[2]]),
    radioButtons(inputId = "cat",
                 label = "Categorized by:",
                 names(df[,3:5]))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("scatter")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$scatter <- renderPlot({

    select_row_year <- df$year %in% input$range[1]:input$range[2]
    y_indices <- which(colnames(df) == input$yaxis)
    color <- which(colnames(df) == input$cat)

    ggplot(df[select_row_year, ], aes_string(x = "year",
                                             y = colnames(df)[y_indices],
                                             color = colnames(df)[color])) + 
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "Overview", color = "Legend") +
      xlab("Year") + ylab(input$yaxis) + theme_minimal()
  })
  }
```

I hope it will help you. I made your legend y axis interactive.

Edit 1 :

Is it something like this that you are looking for :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("range",
                "Year:", min = 1990,
                max = 2040, value = c(2000, 2020)),
    textOutput("SliderText"),
    selectInput("yaxis",
                "Y Variable",
                names(df[,c(2,7)]),
                selected = names(df)[[2]]),
    radioButtons(inputId = "cat",
                 label = "Categorized by:",
                 names(df[,3:5])),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "city",
                       label = "No city choice",
                       choices = NULL,
                       selected = NULL)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("scatter")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    if(input$cat  == "city"){
     updateCheckboxGroupInput(session=session, inputId = "city",
                             label = "Select city",
                             choices = levels(df$city),
                             selected = NULL)
    }
  })

  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    if(length(input$city) != 0){
      select_row <- df$year %in% input$range[1]:input$range[2] & df$city %in% input$city
    }else{
      select_row <- df$year %in% input$range[1]:input$range[2]
    }
    y_indices <- which(colnames(df) == input$yaxis)
    color <- which(colnames(df) == input$cat)

    ggplot(df[select_row, ], aes_string(x = "year",
                                             y = colnames(df)[y_indices],
                                             color = colnames(df)[color])) + 
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "Overview", color = "Legend") +
      xlab("Year") + ylab(input$yaxis) + theme_minimal()
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
This works also very good!

Maybe one additional question here, since you already wrote the code, what would I have to change to make a sort of a filter. So that I can chose for instance only DC or DC and NY or all 3 cities ?Do i have to use checkbox instead of radioButton? Or do I have to build some sort of a filter ?

In case it does not take you to much time could you show me ont he code you provided what you would change in order to make a filter ?